# How does Windows 11 implement the search input in the taskbar?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-10, winui-3, user32

I am looking to build an app that will live on the taskbar but needs to have an extended size (i.e. not just be a square icon). I know that these types of apps are extremely uncommon in the Windows world, but nonetheless, the search box on the taskbar in Windows 10/11 is the closest to what I need.

What API(s) does that search app use?

Is there another app out there (ideally open source) that does something similar?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355530/is-it-possible-to-add-a-deskband-or-similar-to-the-notification-area-in-win-10

Comment: Windows implements the taskbar and can put whatever it wants there. That doesn't mean there's a public API to add custom widgets. From a minute of searching, the closest I see is [Application Desktop Toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/application-desktop-toolbars)

Comment: The designers of the OS don't want you to do this, so it's worth pausing to consider that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to Windows 7, apps can implement custom [Deskbands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/cc144099(v=vs.85)) directly on the Taskbar. However, that feature is [deprecated after Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#deskbands) (also see [Is it possible to add a DeskBand (or similar) to the Notification Area in Win 10/11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74355530/)).

Going forward, Microsoft wants apps to use [Thumbnail/Live Previews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#thumbnails) and [Thumbnail Toolbars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/taskbar-extensions#thumbnail-toolbars) instead.